# Disabling resize?

Tags: cmd, terminal

I'd like to know how to disable terminal window's resizing?
I mean, so user cannot drag a side or corner of the terminal and it didn't change the resolution of the window.

Hope you all understand.

Comment: That's controlled by whatever window manager you are using, and is not a programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I came up with:

```
@echo off

FOR /F "delims=" %%G in ('powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted $host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize.Height') do SET height=%%G
echo %height%

IF /I "%height%" GEQ "37" mode con: cols=100 lines=37
IF /I "%height%" LEQ "36" mode con: cols=100 lines=37

pause
```

This part uses powershell in it in order to figure out the CMD window height. It then puts it into variable %height%.

```
IF /I "%height%" GEQ "37" mode con: cols=100 lines=37
```

This part says ok if the height we found is greater than or equal to 37 then lets change the buffersize/window size to 37.

```
IF /I "%height%" LEQ "36" mode con: cols=100 lines=37
```

This part says if the height we found is less than or equal to 36 then lets change the buffersize/window size to 37.

You could do a .bat file with this code in it (call is resize.bat) and at the end do:
    exit /b

Then from your main .bat file you can do 
    call resize.bat
Then just reference that as often as needed to check the size and resize it.

---

As far as outright disabling it, I don't think you can. Furthermore, people rarely resize a cmd window as there isn't much of a point.

Comment: How about `if "%height%" neq "37" mode...`? Keep in mind, `mode` also does an implicit `cls`, when changing the size